# Applescript, iTunes, and 'date'

Tags: perl, applescript, itunes

I've got an applescript that I call for a song to set the play count and another to set the last played date. These are called from a perl script fetching data from last.fm. Unfortunately, whenever I call the last played date script, I get an error message `setItunesLastPlayed.scpt: execution error: iTunes got an error: A descriptor type mismatch occurred. (-10001)`.

I'm calling it like this:

```
osascript /Users/gms8994/setItunesLastPlayed.scpt "<ARTIST>" "<TITLE>" "Wednesday, July 05, 2011 07:14:11 AM"
```

I did notice that if I request the value of the last play from itunes, it comes back without zero-padding days and hours, so I tried removing those, to no avail.

Here's my script.

```
on run argv
    tell application "iTunes"
        set theArtist to (item 1 of argv)
        set theTitle to (item 2 of argv)
        set theLastPlay to (item 3 of argv)

        set theLastPlay to date theLastPlay

        set results to (every file track of playlist "Library" whose artist contains theArtist and name contains theTitle)
        repeat with t in results
            tell t
                say theLastPlay
                set played date of t to theLastPlay
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end run
```

Can anyone point me to the fix?

Comment: The error is pretty generic. Does your play count script work? Have you tried running the Applescript from the Script Editor or Script Debugger and seeing exactly where it fails?

Comment: @Philip Regan the play count script works correct, as it's just passing in a number. When I run the date script in the editor, with a hard-coded "string" (`set theLastPlay to date "Wednesday, July 05, 2011 07:14:11 AM"`) it works properly.

Comment: I posted a comment below before reading this one here, but I wonder if some kind of conversion is being done when the string is passed from perl to Applescript that causes the string to no longer be parseable in creating the date object.

Answer (score 0):

The `played date` property of a track requires a `date` object, not just the date string. You will need to convert your date into a date object:

```
set newDate to (current date)
set month of newDate to "July"
set year of newDate to "2011"
(* You can fill in the rest *)
set played date of t to newDate
```

I don't think there is a way to directly create a date object from a given string, so you'll have to maintain a function to do that for you in case last.fm (or the technology they rely to store and report back dates) decides to change their date format.

Comment: Isn't that what `set theLastPlay to date theLastPlay` should do?

Comment: Not necessarily. Applescript is dynamically typed to a fault, so when it can't parse your date, it might be trying to set the string itself and returning the error as a result, but the exact behavioir isn't known (at least to me and I have yet to see documentation that tells me otherwise). When I explicitly convert the string to a date and set the date, I was able to set the date without error.